# hide plugin menu at admin side as per access control in nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I had developed plugin which contains plugin menu at admin side & I want to access that plugin menu according to access control in Nopcommerce version 3.40.

So, please let me know how to do that???

I have created plugin menu using, 
`public SiteMapNode BuildMenuItem() method.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IAdminMenuPlugin interface already has "Authenticate" method where you can put any validation logic

Comment: Thank you. You are right & I had already implemented my logic in "Authenticate" method.